# Android - Global Variable keeping its value between all activities

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, global

I need to find a way to keep the value of a variable between various activities. It is infact an integer value which is the counter which would be incremented on each click event. Thus the value should be keep on incrementing if the right button is clicked. The problem that i am having is that the value of this variable does not remain the same (For example if it was 1 on Activity A and the right button has been clicked it should become 2 on Activity B). Could you please help me out? I have tried the singleton Class but to no avail. I have also used the intent getExtras which i am having difficulties in dealing with this part.

```
                 Intent mIntent = getIntent();
         int ScoreCount = mIntent.getIntExtra("intScoreCount", 0);
```

Instead of the value 0 what value can be added so that it retains the value of ScoreCount?

Thank you so much

Comment: use a `SharedPreferences` store, this question comes up almost every other day on SO.

Comment: I dont want the value to be saved in memory instead once the user closes the application the values get back to zero.its just during the life cycle of the application that the values have to be stored and then initialized back to zero.thank you for your help.

Comment: You seem to be confused, in Android, the user does not "close" the app.  Rethink your design.

Comment: I upvoted the question, because there is no stupid question, just stupid answer. The OP tried to find a solution, and just because of bad design (in a question), noone deserves a downvote.

Comment: @ThomasCalc I downvoted it because so many questions of this type pop up on SO that it seems to lack research background, not because it was a stupid question.

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit vague, I meant "stupid" in the way "undesirable". I know questions are also for helping & improving others (and not just the OP), but for this one, I felt downvoting was an overkill (e.g. what if someone avoids it due to the downvote -- someone who could have otherwise given a very detailed good answer to the OP.) Nevermind, not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Based off your responses.
Use SharedPreferences to store/count and reset the count to 0 on app startup. So, either in your Application class or your first Activity, reset the count to 0 so that you are starting over.

Comment: I would personally discourage the use of the application class for this, with the first Activity to be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Application class to do this.
It's the same in all the activities.

Have a look at this post to see how to use it: http://coding-dump.blogspot.ro/2013/01/global-variables-in-android.html

Basically, you extend the Application class and you put your variable there.
You can access the instance of this class and increment you counter.